# Distribute child-views proportionately in vertical linear layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_height = "fill_parent"`.

Now, I add multiple child views to it, sometimes 2 views, at other times 3, based on certain parameters from database, dynamically.

I would like to know how can I, programmatically, distribute these dynamically added childviews in the vertical `LinearLayout`, so that they get distributed uniformly.

BTW, i cannot use `GridView` as I have to embed this `LinearLayout` in horizontal `ScrollView`, and using `GridView` inside horizontal `ScrollView` is highly discouraged.

EDIT: Adding source and xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/serverScreensScreen1LL1"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/serverScreensScreen1SV1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/serverScreensScreen1HSV1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/serverScreensScreen1LL2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout> <!-- Main Container -->
```

SOURCE:

```
private void drawContent()
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(fpfp);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wcwc);
    lp3.weight = 0.3F;

    LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.serverScreensScreen1LL2);

    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) 
    {
            LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ll2.setLayoutParams(new         LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            ll2.setWeightSum(1.0F);

                LinearLayout ll3 = new LinearLayout(this);
                ll3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                ll3.setLayoutParams(lp3);
                    TextView tv1 = new TextView(mContext);
                    tv1.setText("Sample Text A: " + i);
                    tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(12, 34, 56 + i * 8));
                    tv1.setLayoutParams(wcwc);
                ll3.addView(tv1);


                LinearLayout ll4 = new LinearLayout(this);
                ll4.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                ll4.setLayoutParams(lp3);
                    TextView tv2 = new TextView(mContext);
                    tv2.setText("Sample Text B: " + i);
                    tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(34, 12 + i * 8, 56));
                    tv2.setLayoutParams(wcwc);
                ll4.addView(tv2);

                LinearLayout ll5 = new LinearLayout(this);
                ll5.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                ll5.setLayoutParams(lp3);            
                    TextView tv3 = new TextView(mContext);
                    tv3.setText("Sample Text C: " + i);
                    tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(56 + i * 8, 34, 12));
                    tv3.setLayoutParams(wcwc);
                ll5.addView(tv3);

            ll2.addView(ll3);
            ll2.addView(ll4);
            ll2.addView(ll5);

        ll1.addView(ll2);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions plz...

Comment: set the gravity on each child before adding it to the LinearLayout to 1

Comment: on each child, set android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: that dint worked, already tried :(...

Comment: Nitin Bansal, try also one time. layout_weight - it's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of how you are trying to distribute the views but you can try playing with weights.

Search for `android:weightSum` inside the [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)'s docs.

Comment: Ive updated my question with source files. Could you please see if im missing anything...thnx in advance...

Comment: @NitinBansal: Can you draw or create an image of what you are trying to achieve? Having a `ScrollView` with an `HorizontalScrollView` inside doesn't look good.

Comment: @Sure...here's the drawing of vat i want: http://twitpic.com/8kor38 .... btw, i embedded everything inside scrollview to account for the case when i will be needing many rows, thus, occupying more visible area than avaiable. If u can suggest a better alternative, please let me know. Even Im not in favour of doing this